# How to get vector for a sentence from the word2vec of tokens in sentence

Tags: word2vec

I have generated the vectors for a list of tokens from a large document using word2vec. Given a sentence, is it possible to get the vector of the sentence from the vector of the tokens in the sentence.

Answer (score 107):

There are differet methods to get the sentence vectors :

1. **Doc2Vec** : you can train your dataset using Doc2Vec and then use the sentence vectors.
2. **Average of Word2Vec vectors** : You can just take the average of all the word vectors in a sentence. This average vector will represent your sentence vector.
3. **Average of Word2Vec vectors with TF-IDF** : this is one of the best approach which I will recommend. Just take the word vectors and multiply it with their TF-IDF scores. Just take the average and it will represent your sentence vector.

Comment: Why average versus sum?

Comment: To handle variable length sentences

Comment: You're taking the averages of the w2v reps of *N* words for a sentence of length *N*; I get that. But why the average versus, e.g. the sum? (which would also get you a compound rep for sentences of variable lengths)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, or even better, give a code example for option 3

Comment: Here I found a example of 2-3 http://nadbordrozd.github.io/blog/2016/05/20/text-classification-with-word2vec/

Comment: not sure why to do an average of values of each dimension, may be we can just sum and still get similar results.

Comment: How do you handle different vector sizes when multiplying in option 3?

Comment: @neel Any difference, or your preference, between methods 1 and 3?

Comment: @JohnStrood I will go with the first one

Comment: Are there any implementations of these methods for python? E.g. in Gensim? I am looking but i don't really know what terms to search for.

Comment: the problem with the sum, is that the length of the sentence will leave a very strong signal, and if you wish to catch the essence of the combination of the words, this data source will be just noise. for example- consider an effort to cluster sentences. very short sentences like "fast" will tend to be far from long sentences which have the same meaning "fast fast fast"

Answer (score 40):

There are several ways to get a vector for a sentence. Each approach has advantages and shortcomings. Choosing one depends on the task you want to perform with your vectors.

First, you can simply average the vectors from word2vec. According to [Le and Mikolov](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf), this approach performs poorly for sentiment analysis tasks, because it "loses the word order in the same way as the standard bag-of-words models do" and "fail[s] to recognize many sophisticated linguistic phenomena, for instance sarcasm". On the other hand, according to [Kenter et al. 2016](http://aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-1089.pdf), "simply averaging word embeddings of all words in a text has proven to be a strong baseline or feature across a multitude of tasks", such as short text similarity tasks. A variant would be to weight word vectors with their TF-IDF to decrease the influence of the most common words.

A more sophisticated approach developed by [Socher et al.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf) is to combine word vectors in an order given by a parse tree of a sentence, using matrix-vector operations. This method works for sentences sentiment analysis, because it depends on parsing.

Answer (score 29):

It is possible, but not from word2vec. The composition of word vectors in order to obtain higher-level representations for sentences (and further for paragraphs and documents) is a really active research topic. There is not one best solution to do this, it really depends on to what task you want to apply these vectors. You can try concatenation, simple summation, pointwise multiplication, convolution etc. There are several publications on this that you can learn from, but ultimately you just need to experiment and see what fits you best.

Comment: I am trying to classify documents using the token vectors. Since I have too many tokens (200k), I wanted to generate the vectors of the documents to classify, this will reduce the factors substantially (say 500). Was wondering if this is possible.

Comment: You can start from these:  
1. Mitchell, 2008. Vector-based Models of Semantic Composition. [link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/s0453356/composition.pdf )  
2. Blacoe, 2012. A Comparison of Vector-based Representations for Semantic Composition. [link](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D12-1050 )

Comment: 3. Detecting Compositionality of Multi-Word Expressions using Nearest Neighbours in Vector Space Models (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dk427/papers/emnlp2013.pdf)  
4. Prior Disambiguation of Word Tensors for Constructing Sentence Vectors http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/5725/karts_sadr_emnlp.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the papers, appreciate it

Answer (score 25):

It depends on the usage:

1) If you only want to get sentence vector for some known data. Check out  paragraph vector in these papers:

Quoc V. Le and Tomas Mikolov. 2014. Distributed representations of sentences and documents. Eprint Arxiv,4:1188–1196.

A. M. Dai, C. Olah, and Q. V. Le. 2015. DocumentEmbedding with Paragraph Vectors. ArXiv e-prints,July.

2) If you want a model to estimate sentence vector for unknown(test) sentences with unsupervised approach:

You could check out this paper:

[Steven Du and Xi Zhang. 2016. Aicyber at SemEval-2016 Task 4: i-vector based sentence representation. In Proceedings of the 10th International Workshop on Semantic Evaluation (SemEval 2016), San Diego, US](https://github.com/StevenLOL/aicyber_semeval_2016_ivector)

3)Researcher are also looking for the output of certain layer in RNN or LSTM network, recent example is:

http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/view/12195

4)For the gensim doc2vec, many researchers could not get good results, to overcome this problem, following paper using doc2vec based on pre-trained word vectors.

[Jey Han Lau and Timothy Baldwin (2016). An Empirical Evaluation of doc2vec with Practical Insights into Document Embedding Generation. In Proceedings of the 1st Workshop on Representation Learning for NLP, 2016.](https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec)

5) [tweet2vec](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tweet2vec&type=) or [sent2vec](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec)
.

Facebook has SentEval project for evaluating the quality of sentence vectors.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/SentEval

6) There are more information in the following paper:

Neural Network Models for Paraphrase Identification, Semantic Textual Similarity, Natural Language Inference, and Question Answering

---

And for now you can use 'BERT':

Google release the source code as well as pretrained models.

https://github.com/google-research/bert

And here is an example to run bert as a service:

https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service

Answer (score 10):

You can get vector representations of sentences during training phase (join the test and train sentences in a single file and run word2vec code obtained from following link).

Code for sentence2vec has been shared by Tomas Mikolov [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/word2vec-toolkit/Q49FIrNOQRo/J6KG8mUj45sJ).
It assumes first word of a line to be sentence-id.
Compile the code using

```
gcc word2vec.c -o word2vec -lm -pthread -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops
```

and run it using

```
./word2vec -train alldata-id.txt -output vectors.txt -cbow 0 -size 100 -window 10 -negative 5 -hs 0 -sample 1e-4 -threads 40 -binary 0 -iter 20 -min-count 1 -sentence-vectors 1
```

**EDIT**

Gensim (development version) seems to have a method to infer vectors of new sentences. Check out `model.infer_vector(NewDocument)` method in https://github.com/gojomo/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec.py

Answer (score 5):

I've had good results from:

1. Summing the word vectors (with tf-idf weighting).  This ignores word order, but for many applications is sufficient (especially for short documents)
2. [Fastsent](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/630)

Answer (score 5):

Google's Universal Sentence Encoder embeddings are an updated solution to this problem. It doesn't use Word2vec but results in a competing solution.

Here is [a walk-through with TFHub and Keras](https://www.dlology.com/blog/keras-meets-universal-sentence-encoder-transfer-learning-for-text-data/).

Answer (score 1):

Deep averaging network (DAN) can provide sentence embeddings in which word  bi-grams are averaged and passed through feedforward deep neural network(DNN).

It is found that transfer learning using sentence embeddings tends to outperform word level transfer as it preserves the semantic relationship.

You don't need to start the training from scratch, the pretrained DAN models are available for perusal ( Check Universal Sentence Encoder module in google hub).

Comment: I believe you were downvoted because you don't answer the question. That being said, this approach is handy for people who do not want to work with their own trained Word2Vec model. Here is a link for the readers: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2

Answer (score 1):

let suppose this is current sentence

```
import gensim 
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim import models
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path of your trainig 
dataset', binary=True)

strr = 'i am'
strr2 = strr.split()
print(strr2)
model[strr2] //this the the sentance embeddings.
```