# How can a sentence or a document be converted to a vector?

Tags: vector, nlp, word2vec

We have models for converting words to vectors (for example the word2vec model). Do similar models exist which convert sentences/documents into vectors, using perhaps the vectors learnt for the individual words?

Comment: @alvas, Can you clarify what you want in your answer. Perhaps I can help.

Comment: @azarel, i'm just attracting attention to this post and perhaps something good will come out of it if more people answer and perhaps find some not so popular but cool way to model sentences as vectors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760935/how-to-get-vector-for-a-sentence-from-the-word2vec-of-tokens-in-sentence/29891392

Answer (score 50):

1) Skip gram method: [paper here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpapers.nips.cc%2Fpaper%2F5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf&ei=FdyHVeeNDMqhugSShZugAg&usg=AFQjCNH4-Ecded1JdFimktgajA3mvcdXaQ&sig2=5hiJmQ0XYxBX639t-gJ2jw&bvm=bv.96339352,d.c2E) and the tool that uses it, [google word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)

2) Using [LSTM-RNN](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06922) to form semantic representations of sentences.

3) Representations of [sentences and documents](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.stanford.edu%2F~quocle%2Fparagraph_vector.pdf&ei=Ct2HVa-9GcOMuAS3-oDoDA&usg=AFQjCNESECVF_9eXAkAjfSqqHrqlxkVQgg&sig2=ozIjjEKK9rqrn4T0wabTQw&bvm=bv.96339352,d.c2E). The Paragraph vector is introduced in this paper. It is basically an unsupervised algorithm that learns fixed-length feature representations from variable-length pieces of texts, such as sentences, paragraphs, and documents.

4) Though this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00075) does not form sentence/paragraph vectors, it is simple enough to do that. One can just plug in the individual word vectors([Glove](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf) [word vectors](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) are found to give the best performance) and then can form a vector representation of the whole sentence/paragraph.

5) Using a [CNN](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3830.pdf) to [summarize](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01710) documents.

Comment: It worth to mention which solution is actually using individual word vectors to form a vector for a document. It seems few of them are using learnt word vectors.

Answer (score 17):

It all depends on:

- which vector model you're using
- what is the purpose of the model
- your creativity in combining word vectors into a document vector

If you've generated the model using Word2Vec, you can either try:

- **Doc2Vec**: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html
- **Wiki2Vec**: https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec

Or you can do what some people do, i.e. sum all content words in the documents and divide by the content words, e.g. https://github.com/alvations/oque/blob/master/o.py#L13 (note: line 17-18 is a hack to reduce noise):

```
def sent_vectorizer(sent, model):
    sent_vec = np.zeros(400)
    numw = 0
    for w in sent:
        try:
            sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, model[w])
            numw+=1
        except:
            pass
    return sent_vec / np.sqrt(sent_vec.dot(sent_vec))
```

Comment: diving the final result with the number of words won't normalize the vector. It is better if you divide it by size of the vector: `sent_vec / np.sqrt(sent_vec.dot(sent_vec))`

Answer (score 16):

A solution that is slightly less off the shelf, but probably hard to beat in terms of accuracy if you have a specific thing you're trying to do:

Build an RNN (with LSTM or GRU memory cells, [comparison here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3555.pdf)) and optimize the error function of the actual task you're trying to accomplish. You feed it your sentence, and train it to produce the output you want. The activations of the network after being fed your sentence is a representation of the sentence (although you might only care about the networks output).

You can represent the sentence as a sequence of one-hot encoded characters, as a sequence of one-hot encoded words, or as a sequence of word vectors (e.g. [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) or [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)). If you use word vectors, you can keep backpropagating into the word vectors, updating their weights, so you also get custom word vectors tweaked specifically for the task you're doing.

Comment: This is a good solution when you have lots of labeled data to do a supervised RNN training. When you have lots of unlabeled data, I'd prefer doing a unsupervised PV embedding on the whole dataset. And then do a logistic regression training on a smaller labelled training set.

Comment: @justint For the sentence embedding using RNN as far as I know you dont need to have labeled data

Comment: @sarii This is true. You could just predict the next word (do language modelling), and optionally fine-tune that network on labelled data. This answer is a bit old though - these days Transformer based architectures usually have the best performance for language tasks like this.

Answer (score 15):

There are a lot of ways to answer this question. The answer depends on your interpretation of phrases and sentences.

These distributional models such as `word2vec` which provide vector representation for each word can only show how a word usually is used in a window-base context in relation with other words. Based on this interpretation of context-word relations, you can take average vector of all words in a sentence as vector representation of the sentence. For example, in this sentence:

> vegetarians eat vegetables .

[image: V_s]

We can take the normalised vector as vector representation:

[image: V(sentence)]

The problem is in compositional nature of sentences. If you take the average word vectors as above, these two sentences have the same vector representation:

> vegetables eat vegetarians .

There are a lot of researches in distributional fashion to learn tree structures through corpus processing. For example: [Parsing With Compositional Vector Grammars](http://www.socher.org/index.php/Main/ParsingWithCompositionalVectorGrammars). This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJozqoejJnA) also explain this method.

Again I want to emphasise on interpretation. These sentence vectors probably have their own meanings in your application. For instance, in sentiment analysis in [this project in Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/), the meaning that they are seeking is the positive/negative sentiment of a sentence. Even if you find a perfect vector representation for a sentence, there are philosophical debates that these are not actual meanings of sentences if you cannot judge the truth condition (David Lewis "General Semantics" 1970). That's why there are lines of works focusing on computer vision ([this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02598.pdf) or [this paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/SocherKarpathyLeManningNg_TACL2013.pdf)). My point is that it can completely depend on your application and interpretation of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you welcome an implementation. I faced the similar problem in converting the movie plots for analysis, after trying many other solutions I sticked to an implementation that made my job easier. The code snippet is attached below.

Install 'spaCy' from the [following link.](https://spacy.io/usage/)

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(YOUR_DOC_HERE)
vec = doc.vector
```

Hope this helps.