# How to automatically label a cluster of words using semantics?

Tags: python, r, nlp, nltk, wordnet

The context is : I already have clusters of words (phrases actually) resulting from kmeans applied to internet search queries and using common urls in the results of the search engine as a distance (co-occurrence of urls rather than words if I simplify a lot).

I would like to automatically label the clusters using semantics, in other words I'd like to extract the main concept surrounding a group of phrases considered together.

For example - sorry for the subject of my example - if I have the following bunch of queries : ['my husband attacked me','he was arrested by the police','the trial is still going on','my husband can go to jail for harrassing me ?','free lawyer']
My study deals with domestic violence, but clearly this cluster is focused on the legal aspect of the problem so the label could be "legal" for example.

I am new to NPL but I have to precise that I don't want to extract words using POS tagging (or at least this is not the expected final outcome but maybe a necessary preliminary step).

I read about Wordnet for sense desambiguation and I think that might be a good track, but I don't want to calculate similarity between two queries (since the clusters are the input) nor obtain the definition of one selected word thanks to the context provided by the whole bunch of words (which word to select in this case ?). I want to use the whole bunch of words to provide a context (maybe using synsets or categorization with the xml structure of the wordnet) and then summarize the context in one or few words.

Any ideas ? I can use R or python, I read a little about nltk but I don't find a way to use it in my context.

Comment: Have you looked at the packages topicmodel and mallet?  You want to identify topics in your clusters, it seems.

Comment: No I havent, thanks for the suggestion I will have a look!

Comment: @lawyerR i had a look and  saw that LDA or more generally modelling toping uses words already being part of the initial set. It is not really my situation, in my example the legal dimension comes from shared semantics not higher frequency of the legal word itself. hence the wordnet idea

Comment: The problem is a bit philosophical. For example in your sample, the topic might be "crime" instead of "legal". Maybe you should have cluster of topics (few words as topics) in parallel to your cluster of phrases. Then you can assign a sorted list of words as topic. It's what LDA is all about. As I understand "semantic" for you is actually the topic of the phrase.

Comment: @lawyeR topic models do not provide meaningful names to the resultant topics. Besides, The OP already knows what the "topics" are (k-means clusters).

Comment: @Mehdi, I totally agree, but I will be ok with "crime" as well, I don't care about the chosen word, I care about the global semantic. To get a cluster of topics in parallel, I guess I would have to create it manually. To make it automatic, I think about wordnet and context desambiguition using smart dictionnaries, but having no experience in that, I don't really know where to begin

Comment: @clemtoy, you seem pretty aware of NLP problems in python, would you mind me asking if you have an idea for my question ?

Comment: See this question and its answers: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/how-to-give-name-to-topics-created-using-lda

Comment: @jknappen thanks for the suggestion, I do ask pretty the same question than the one you pointed out, but the answers are quite poor so far, I just have some phrases so I am pretty sure TF-IDF and ngrams analysis will not take me very far. I am really looking for some kind of ontologies like wordnet classification.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is probably is to label the clusters manually, especially if there are few of them. This a difficult problem even for humans to solve, because you might need a domain expert. Anyone claiming they could do that automatically and reliably (except in some very limited domains) is probably running a startup and trying to get your business.

Also, going through the clusters yourself will have benefits. 1) you may discover you had the wrong number of clusters (k parameter) or that there was too much junk in the input to begin with. 2) you will gain qualitative insight into what is being talked about and what topic there are in the data (which you probably can't know before looking at the data). Therefore, label manually if qualitative insight is what you are after. If you need quantitative result too, you could then train a classifier on the manually labelled topics to 1) predict topics for the rest of the clusters, or 2) for future use, if you repeat the clustering, get new data, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you should edit it and move it to comments. It is not a proper answer to my question since I want to do this automatically. Maybe it is not possible at this point, maybe other people have ideas or been confronted to the same problem. I don't have enough clusters to train an algorithm and even, I would have to do the labelling manually first on the train test. So... I'm not saying that it is not relevant to do so (I will actually do it manually to compare with the automatic approach), but still not a proper answer to my question... Thanks though

Comment: Stéphanie, if you don't have enough clusters to train an algorithm, follow his advice in the first paragraph; if you do, or ready for when you do, follow the advice in the second paragraph :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook, there are other tracks, not everything has to be treated manually or with machine learning ;-), I am following a track [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902411/how-to-get-domain-of-words-using-wordnet-in-python] and will do a feedback if it acutally solves my pb

Comment: it is a very inspiring beginning of answer from @Alvas to a close question (but identifying a domain per word doesn't entirely solve my pb, I have to keep digging)

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about semantics in this area we mean *Statistical Semantics*. The statistical or distributional semantics is very different from other definitions of semantics which has logic and reasoning behind it. Statistical semantics is based on *Distributional Hypothesis*, which considers context as meaning aspect of words and phrases. Meaning in very abstract and general sense in different litterers is called *topics*. There are several unsupervised methods for modelling topics, such as LDA or even word2vec, which basically provide word similarity metric or suggest a list of similar words for a document as another context. Usually when you have these unsupervised clusters, you need a *domain expert* to tell the meaning of each cluster.

However, for several reasons you might accept low accuracy assignment of a word as the *general topic* (or as in your words "global semantic") to a list of phrases. If this is the case, I would suggest to take a look at Word Sense Disambiguation tasks which look for coarse grained word senses. For WordNet, it might be called supersense tagging task.

This paper worth to take a look: [More or less supervised supersense tagging of Twitter](http://aclweb.org/anthology/S14-1001)

And about your question about choosing words from current phrases, there is also an active question about "converting phrase to vectors", my answer to that question in `word2vec` fashion might be useful:
[How can a sentence or a document be converted to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795944/how-can-a-sentence-or-a-document-be-converted-to-a-vector/30866285#30866285)

I can add more related papers later if it comes to my mind.

Comment: Thank you @Mehdi, I will have a look at these references !

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Automatic Labelling of Topic Models](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P11-1154) explains the author's approach to this problem. To provide an overview I can tell you that they generate some label candidates using the information retrieved from Wikipedia and Google, and once they have the list of candidates in place they rank those candidates to find the best label.
I think the code is not available online, but I have not looked for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reactivating my question ! I will have a look at your reference and come back here

Answer (score 1):

The package [chowmein](https://github.com/xiaohan2012/chowmein) claims to do this in python using the algorithm outlined in [Automatic Labeling of Multinomial Topic Models](http://sifaka.cs.uiuc.edu/czhai/pub/kdd07-label.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, which the below papers suggest is identifying the set of keywords from the cluster, getting all the synonyms and then finding the hypernyms for each synonym.
The idea is to get a more abstract meaning for the cluster by using the hypernym.
Example: A word cluster containing words `dog` and `wolf` should not be labelled with either word but as `canids`. They achieve it using synonymy and hypernymy.

[Cluster Labeling by Word Embeddings
and WordNet’s Hypernymy](https://aclanthology.org/U18-1008.pdf)

[Automated Text Clustering and Labeling using Hypernyms](https://www.ripublication.com/ijaer19/ijaerv14n2_16.pdf)