# Sentence feature vectors

Tags: neural-network

How could one, in an unsupervised environment, get a feature vectors for a sentence. I believe for an image data one could build a conv auto encoder and take the hidden layers outputs. What would be the best way to do this for RNN type models (LSTM, GRU, etc.).

Would this (https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5271-pre-training-of-recurrent-neural-networks-via-linear-autoencoders.pdf) be on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be doing something with the word2vec representations of all the words (like summing them?).

See this post:
[How to get vector for a sentence from the word2vec of tokens in sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760935/how-to-get-vector-for-a-sentence-from-the-word2vec-of-tokens-in-sentence)

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem but I'm not doing language per say. I just put sentence to give scope to my problem. (list of categorical items) -> (feature vector with semantic 'understanding')