# How can I use word2vec to train a classifier?

Tags: python, word2vec, naivebayes

The code is used to generate word2vec and use it to train the naive Bayes classifier.
I am able to generate word2vec and use the similarity functions successfully.As a next step I would want to use the word2vec to train the naive bayes classifier. Currently the code given an error when I am trying to slit the data in test and training. How do i convert word2vec model into the array so that it can be used as training data.

# Importing the libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import gensim

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Restaurant_Reviews.tsv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)

# Cleaning the texts
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
corpus = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['Review'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
#    for word2vec we want an array of vectors

    corpus.append(review)

#print(corpus)
X = gensim.models.Word2Vec(corpus, min_count=1,size=1000)
#print (X.most_similar("love"))


#embedding_matrix = np.zeros(len(X.wv.vocab), dtype='float32')
#for i in range(len(X.wv.vocab)):
#    embedding_vector = X.wv[X.wv.index2word[i]]
#    if embedding_vector is not None:
#        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

# Creating the Bag of Words model
#from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
#cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
#X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)

# Fitting Naive Bayes to the Training set
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

It gives an error on line -
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec'>
```

Comment: You need to use convert your corpus to vectors using your embeddings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760935/how-to-get-vector-for-a-sentence-from-the-word2vec-of-tokens-in-sentence

Answer (score 4):

Word2Vec provides word embeddings only. If you want to characterize documents by embeddings, you'll need to perform an averaging/summing/max operation on embeddings of all words from each document to have a D-dimensional vector that can be used for classification. See [here](https://www.mira.law/blogposts/2017/5/12/semantic-averaging-of-documents-using-word2vec-representations) and [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221715/apply-word-embeddings-to-entire-document-to-get-a-feature-vector) for further information on this.

Otherwise, you can use Doc2Vec model to directly produce document embeddings, for which gensim also gives a very good provider.

Comment: The link to "here" is broken

Answer (score 1):

You have vectors for each word, now you have two approaches to move forward, one could be simply take average of all the words in a sentence to find the sentence vector, another could be to use tfidf.

I implemented the average approach in one of my ongoing projects and i am sharing the github link, please go to the heading "text vectorization(word2vec)" and you will find the code their.
https://github.com/abhibhargav29/SentimentAnalysis/blob/master/SentimentAnalysis.ipynb. I would however suggest you to read data cleaning before as well to understand it in a better way.

One important advice: Do not split the data into train, cv, test after vectorization, do it before vectorization or you will overfit the model.

Comment: The link is not working